# Creating custom event for hiding a control not working

Tags: c#, events

Here is my code in my `userControl`

```
public partial class UserControlHomeScreen : UserControl
{
    public event EventHandler SomethingHappened;

    public void DoSomething()
    {
        EventHandler handler = SomethingHappened;
        if (handler != null)
        {
            handler(this, EventArgs.Empty);
        }
    }

    public void HandleEvent(object sender, EventArgs args)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Wafak.");
    }

    public UserControlHomeScreen()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void btnAverageDailyBal_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        this.Tag = 0;
        this.Hide();
    }

    private void btnComputeTransferPricing_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        this.Tag = 1;
        this.Hide();
    }
}
```

And here is my code in my main form

```
private void HomeScreen()
    {
        uHomeScreen = new UserControlHomeScreen();
        uHomeScreen.Dock = DockStyle.Fill;  
        //uHomeScreen.Disposed += new EventHandler(uHomeScreen_Disposed);
        uHomeScreen.SomethingHappened += new EventHandler(uHomeScreen_SomethingHappened);
        panelMain.Controls.Add(uHomeScreen);
    }

    void uHomeScreen_SomethingHappened(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("throw new NotImplementedException();");
    }
```

What i want to happen is that when the usercontrol is hidden i want to fire an event in my main form but does not work, what am i missing? please help. thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your naming convention for event raiser (`DoSomething`) is confusing, your code doesn't call `DoSomething` (or raise the event `SomethingHappened`), so how could it fire for you? Add the following code in your user control class:

```
//override the OnVisibleChanged
protected override void OnVisibleChanged(EventArgs e){
  if(!Visible) DoSomething();
}
```